# Using JSON with Michael hartl tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I would like to save a JSON file in the JavaScript folder and read data from it and save the data to the database. How do I read a JSON file in Ruby on Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a `respond_to` block in your controller, return JSON data and parse it with JavaScript in your view.

If you need to view the straight JSON data just add ".json" (www.your_url.com.json) to the end of the url in your browser and you'll see the data returned, in which case you can copy it and save it wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do i return json data and parse it with javascript? i am a newbie at rails.

Comment: Here's a tutorial that explains it better than I can here. http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: i have added the respond_to block but still wondering how do i indicate the location of the .json file with the data?

Comment: The json data is returned to the view, not saved to a file. You can, however, view the data in your browser by adding .json to the end of your url.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, i have understood how to return json data and parse it with js.